# Using handler to send multiple messages

Tags: java, android, handler

I am using a handler in background thread which will execute the messages after being received. I receive a Intent from main activity to my service and call the following actions. Like, I have first message to execute the socket connection which works fine. But the other following messages doesn't seem to work. Am I using the `handler properly`. Here is my following code.

```
if (action.equals("com.example.app.START")){

            Message message = new Message();
            message.what = 1;
            foo.handler.sendMessage(message);

        } else if (action.equals("com.example.app.HALLO")){

            Message message2 = new Message();
            message2.what = 2;
            foo.handler.sendMessage(message2);
        } ...
```

Like wise I have two more messages lined Up. This is my handler in my thread.

```
public class foo extends Thread {

    public Handler handler;
    public Looper looper;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();

        handler = new Handler(){
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                if (msg.what == 1){
                   Log.d(TAG, "Conn established");
                   // Socket connection got connected- works fine  
                } if(msg.what == 2){
                   Log.d(TAG, "second msg received");
                   // this doesn't work..
                   foo.outputMessage();
                }                      
         }
         Looper.loop();   
   }
         private void outputMessage(byte[] message){
         ......
  }
}
```

I have couple more messages like I said,which doesnt work. Am I missing anything ? I am not getting any errors.

Comment: Did you debug if your action ever really does equal "HALLO"? Also please extract those literals into constants, same with "msg.what == 1" rather use enum

Comment: @First action intent `start` receives and the `socket connection` works. I followed exactly the same procedure for the rest.

Comment: How can I use enum ?

Comment: Instead of hardcoded values like "1-2-3" you should use an enum. That won't **fix your code**, it'll just make it less bad

Comment: Achso okie. Do you see any obvious mistake other than that ? Is this the right way ? even the `log tag` is not printed

Comment: I do not see any obvious mistake, other than possibly misspelling "HALLO" instead of "HELLO". That's why you should use a constant, to avoid those possibilities altogether.

Comment: Thanks man. I will look into !